# Schneier's Blowfish

Tags: c++, c, encryption, blowfish

Can someone please show me an example usage of Schneier's Blowfish code (http://www.schneier.com/code/bfsh-sch.zip), i.e. encrypting and decrypting a string with a given key, in C or C++?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: this is not a homework assignment.

Comment: Did you try it yourself? Didn't it work? What did you try?

Comment: Isn't homework - just a personal project. I require implementation of encryption for a (personal) project I'm working on but I'd rather not learn about encryption methods in detail unless I need to. Presumably all I need is an Encrypt(string, key) and Decrypt(string, key) function to implement encryption and that's all I'm trying to get out of Blowfish.

Comment: Wow why is this question getting bad ratings? It's an honest question and I feel I did a reasonable amount of effort initially researching it. I reckon if I spent a day researching Blowfish I could sort this out on my own but it seemed as if it would be simple enough for some kind person who knows their stuff to show me how to use it and save me some time.

Comment: If it's at all supposed to work reliably and you don't want to learn about cryptography, why not just use one of the high-quality free libraries like bcrypt++, beecrypt, mcrypt or openssl?

Comment: @JonaGik: Because basically in short your question reads like "Download some code here and figure out how it works. Then get back to me".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a test

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "blowfish.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned long xl = 1, xr = 2;
  char key[] = "Hello";


  /* NoErr is defined as 0 in the blowfish.c file */
  if (opensubkeyfile () != 0)
  {
    printf ("\nCannot open subkey file");
    perror ("Exit");
    printf ("\n");
    return 1;
  };

  InitializeBlowfish (key, 7);
  Blowfish_encipher (&xl, &xr);

  printf("\n%x %x", xl, xr);

  Blowfish_decipher (&xl, &xr);

  printf("\n%x %x", xl, xr);

  if ((xl == 1) && (xr == 2))
  {
    printf("\nDecipher OK.");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("\nDecipher Fail\n");
  }
  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Please make sure the header file name's character case. Also note the file name `blowfish.dat` is correct.

Also have a look at Paul Kocher's Implementation from this page : http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html

Comment: Thanks for your response! So if I wanted to encrypt a string, I break it into two pieces of equal length (xl and xr) and then proceed? Is "Hello" the encryption key? Where is the function "unsigned long F(unsigned long x)" used? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Also xl and xr are long - what do I do if I want to encrypt a string? Thanks!

Comment: Suggested reading: [http://www.schneier.com/](http://www.schneier.com/) and [http://www.schneier.com/paper-blowfish-fse.html](http://www.schneier.com/paper-blowfish-fse.html). Please read some text, and make your mind work.